# Отфильтровать NaNы через условие

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

При подсчете p-значения на выводе `nan`

```
xbox_one = df[(df['platform'] == 'XOne') & (df['user_score'] != np.nan)]['user_score']
```

Это происходит из-за того, что присутсвуют NaNы. При такой фильтрации (см.выше) все равно в итоге `nan`. Как можно еще отфильтровать NaNы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
df['user_score'] != np.nan
```

`NA` - это специальное значение, которое нельзя проверять через "равно" или "не равно". Его нужно проверять функцией `isna`, ну и ещё нужно сделать отрицание условия с помощью `~`, чтобы получилось "не равно":

```py
~df['user_score'].isna()
```